# Stripe returning it can't find subscription but it exists

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve some info about a Stripe subscription that exists. I know it exists because I checked the dashboard and matched the stripe subscription ID with the one in my DB (copy-pasted to confirm)

My issue is that Stripe is telling me that it is not a valid subscription. However, if I remove the variable and replace it with a string of the subscription ID I am testing with it works. I have checked via `console.log(typeof subscriptionID)` and the variable I am using is, in fact, a string. So it doesn't make sense to me why it is not working.

```
let subscriptionID = JSON.stringify(req.body.user.company.stripe.subscriptionId)
    stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
        subscriptionID)
    .then(subscription => {
        if(subscription.id != null) {
            logger.info(`Retrieved plan successfully`);
            return res.json({success: true, subscription});
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        logger.info(`Error retrieving plan`);
        logger.error(`retrievePlan: Error message: ${err}`);
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({success: false, message: 'Error retrieving your subscription details.'});
    });
```

Here is the link to the Stripe docs

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve

EDIT**

Stack trace/ error message from Stripe

```
stack:
   'Error: No such subscription: "<sub ID>"\n    at Constructor._Error (/home/josh/Documents/Projects/Blah/billing/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:16)\n    at Constructor (/home/josh/Documents/Projects/Blah/billing/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:164:17)\n    at new Constructor (/home/josh/Documents/Projects/Blah/billing/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:164:17)\n    at Function.StripeError.generate (/home/josh/Documents/Projects/Blah/billing/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:57:14)\n    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/home/josh/Documents/Projects/Blah/billing/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:165:39)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)',
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some context. If the string contains a valid id at the time you're making the request, and that same works when hard-coded, then something else is at play.

Comment: @DaveNewton What other context do I need to include? I've provided everything that is related other than my DB model and my actual data. This is inside a function/controller which should have zero impact

Comment: @DaveNewton I've added the stack trace as well as the error message from Stripe

Comment: You've got it working with copy-pasted string, then you could do `console.log(subscriptionID  == "<copy-pasted id>")` to double check the string value

Comment: @Neverever I got it just now, check my answer I replied with. I'd love to understand why it works how it did

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify("id") == "id")`, which prints `false`, because `JSON.stringify` puts extra quote in the string input

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my issue. It was reporting it not as a string even though it was. I removed the JSON.stringify part to make it what I figured was just a literal variable but that ended up making it work properly.

`let subscriptionID = req.body.user.company.stripe.subscriptionId`

Comment: If you `JSON.stringify` a string you'll get quotes around it as part of the string. It'd be a string either way, but the stringified version would have additional quotes.